# cgSceneGraph multiple scenes doesnt works

Tags: jquery

I tryied to add several canvas with cgSceneGraph. But this feature doesn't works. Controls are working only in last scene. All previous are clear and I cann't add controls there.
Some tips here ?

For example I used 01_Text_01_simple project from cgsg package and modified these lines:

```
<canvas id="scene" width="800" height="800" style='border:2px solid black'></canvas>
<canvas id="scene2" width="800" height="800" style='border:2px solid red'></canvas>
```

...

```
var canvasScene = document.getElementById("scene");
var game = new CGMain(canvasScene);
var canvasScene2 = document.getElementById("scene2");
var game2 = new CGMain(canvasScene2);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a known limitation of Scenegraph.js (formerly cgSceneGraph), that you cannot use it on several canvases on the same page.
It will be solved with version 3, but at this time you can only use 1 scene at a time.

If you strongly need to have several canvases on the same page, please raise an issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/GwennaelBuchet/SceneGraph.js/issues
We'll then try to put this feature on top of our list.